# Linear referencing in Geographic Coordinate System (GCS) using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, linear-referencing

I want to make a new line segment in event table with linear referencing ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

I'm using two tools:

1. Create Route with input line feature in Geographic coordinates system and tool
2. Make Route Event Layer with input table event with decimal degree unit.

But when I trying running them, the result is that only half of the events are in the segmentation.

Why are all lines not segmented based on table events?

in segment with low risk i give blue color and high risk in red color, but only low risk display in segment
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please provide more information about your problem (table subset, error messages if any, image of the problem), because the GCS does not seem to be the cause.